# NodeJS: Closing Mongod makes the app crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a NodeJS app, using Mongoose.
Evrything works fine, but when I close the Mongod service (on Windows), I get the following error, which makes my app crash:

```
[DB HANDLER] Error...disconnected undefined
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Socket.<anonymous> (d:\Dev\LinxMainServer\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:325:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! linxwebserver@0.0.1 compile: `tsc && node build/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the linxwebserver@0.0.1 compile script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

What I don't understand is that I handle mongoose.connection events, and I even witnesses going through the "mongoose.connection.on('error', ...)" code during other cases.

Following is the piece of code I'm using in my DB handler .js file:

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("[DB HANDLER] Error");
});

mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
  console.log("[DB HANDLER] Connected to MongoDB");
});

mongoose.connection.on('close', function () {
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] Error...close');
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnecting', function (err) {
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] Error...disconnect', err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function (err) {
    console.log('[DB HANDLER] Error...disconnected', err);
    //connect();  // Creates a loop...
});

mongoose.connection.on('parseError', function (err) {
    console.log('[DB HANDLER] Error...parse', err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('reconnected', function (err) {
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] Reconnected event', err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('reconnectFailed', function (err) {
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] reconnectFailed event', err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('connecting', function (err) {
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] connecting event', err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function (err) {
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] connected event', err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('timeout', function (err) {
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] timeout event', err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('close', function (err) {
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] close event', err);
});




const connect = async function() {
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] Connect()');

  console.log(`[DB HANDLER] Connecting to [${config_handler.config.test_name}] Database`);

  /* Get DB URI */
  var uri = (config_handler.config.db.instance.uri);
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] DB uri: ', uri);

  /* Get Mongoose options */
  var mongooseOpts = (config_handler.config.db.mongoose_opts);
  console.log('[DB HANDLER] mongooseOpts: ', mongooseOpts);

  if(mongooseOpts == null || uri == null){
    console.log('[DB HANDLER][ERROR] Couldnt get DB configuration from env_rec.json file');
  }

  /* Connect to DB */
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(uri, mongooseOpts);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[DB HANDLER][ERROR] Connection error: ", error.reason);
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: But now imagine what happens if something kills Mongo. Mongo itself is not going to send you an event, because it's already gone, so now what happens? The error is about an event `error` getting emitted in a way you don't catch, so we can assume it's not being emitted by the `mongoose.connection` object: what else might need an `.on('error', ...` handler?

Comment: Well, I know it is emitted by node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:325:10. But I don't know how to catch it at this point. I expected it to be transfered to Mongoose ?